# Can we implement tree view with select2?

Tags: jquery, html, css, select, jquery-select2

i am going to implement tree view with select2 plugin. I have tried just basic config. Can you help me with that? 
Desired Result [image]

And here is code i have tried

```js
$('.js-example-basic-single').select2({
  placeholder: 'Select an option'
});
```

```css
select {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css'>
<select name="" id="" class="js-example-basic-single">
    <option value="main">Pepal Inc.</option>
    <option value="child1">Business Unit 1</option>
    <option value="child1">Sub Business Unit 1</option>
    <option value="child-level1">Sub Sub Business Unit 1</option> 
    <option value="child-level1">Business Unit 2</option>
    <option value="child-level1">Business Unit 3</option>
    <option value="child1">Sub Business Unit 3</option>
    <option value="child-level1">Sub Sub Business Unit 3</option> 
</select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a real "TREE" plugin here:
https://github.com/clivezhg/select2-to-tree

Compat: Select2 4+

[image]

Comment: Demo available?

Comment: Download the zip from github, there's a demo in example folder